# Regex for at least one alphabet and shouldn't allow dot(.)

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regular-language

I have written the regex below but I'm facing an issue:

```
^[^\.]*[a-zA-Z]+$
```

As per the above regex, `df45543` is invalid, but I want to allow such a string. Only one alphabet character is mandatory and a dot is not allowed. All other characters are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookahead to enforce one alphabet:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[^.]+$
```

`(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` is a positive lookahead that makes sure there is at least one alphabet in the input.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the digits as allowed characters:

```
^[^\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP2dN0/1)

In case you need to disallow dots, and allow at least 1 English letter, then use lookaheads:

```
^(?!.*\.)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

`(?!.*\.)` disallows a dot in the string, and `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` requires at least one English letter.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP2dN0/2)

Another scenario is when the dot is not allowed only at the beginning. Then, use

```
^(?!\.)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
^[^.a-z]*[a-z][^.]*$
```

(Use a case insensitive mode, or add `A-Z` in the character classes)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the first part of your regex which is `^[^.]*` to the end to be like this

`^[^.]*[A-Za-z]+[^.]*$`

try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV9cC4/1)